# detect canceled scroll in scrollView with paging enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I want to detect when a user scrolls to the next page (in a collectionView with paging enabled). As soon as the user begins scrolling to the next cell i prepare it using the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function. Here I set a variable indicating which will be the next visible cell.

Then, when the user stops dragging, I run the visual updates using the `scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)` function. At this point I know which cell is visible because I saved that in the variable before.

However, when the user starts dragging the collectionView and then scrolls back to the starting view, the `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` already saved the next item. This leads the following function (`scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)`) to run incorrect code (visual updates).

Is there any way of knowing when a user canceled or actually executed a scroll to the next page, so that I can stop `scrollViewDidEndDragging` from updating unless the scroll was "successful"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using the function `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)` and looking at the `targetContentOffset` parameter. if the it is more than half the width of the page in either direction, the scrolling was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the scrollview’s .contentOffset from didStartDragging and didEndDragging. 
The paging animation is successful if and only if the contentOffset changed

Comment: unfortunately, even if the contentOffset changed in didEndDragging, if the scrolling doesn't have enough velocity (or velocity in backwards direction), the collectionView will return to the starting page and therefore the scrolling will have "failed"